# How to test function arg to be number with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

How can I test if a function arg it's a number?
I got a simple function of leap year, so I'd like to test if the user inputs a number (not string nor boolean) in "year" argument.

`const isLeapYear = (year) => ((year % 100 === 0) ? (year % 400 === 0) : (year % 4 === 0));`

I tried to use mock function but didn't work and I have no idea of a solution. Does anybody can help me please?

```
  it('Verify if the function argument is a number', () => {
     const myMock = jest.fn(2021);
     myMock.mock.calls[0].toBe(expect.any(Number));
  });
```

Comment: Can you work in `!isNaN(arg)`?

Comment: How the Jest use this @Abe?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're testing exactly.  I don't know why Jest is being used - Jest is dev-facing, so it won't tell you what the user does with your code.  If you want to know what the user does in production, you could modify your function to be something like this: `const isLeapYear = year => { if isNaN(parseInt(year)) throw new Error('year must be a number'); return <your logic here>; };`

Comment: I got your point. Actually I'd like to test it with Jest, not touching the function. So basically  it's not possible to directly test the argument with Jest in test file?